# Invoking object properties in Delphi

Tags: delphi, properties

I admit I'm not a Delphi expert, so I need some advice.
I have a pre-built class with this definition

```
  TS7Helper = class
  private
    function GetInt(pval: pointer): smallint;
    procedure SetInt(pval: pointer; const Value: smallint);
    function GetWord(pval: pointer): word;
    procedure SetWord(pval: pointer; const Value: word);
    function GetDInt(pval: pointer): longint;
    procedure SetDInt(pval: pointer; const Value: longint);
    function GetDWord(pval: pointer): longword;
    procedure SetDWord(pval: pointer; const Value: longword);
    function GetDateTime(pval: pointer): TDateTime;
    procedure SetDateTime(pval: pointer; const Value: TDateTime);
    function GetReal(pval: pointer): single;
    procedure SetReal(pval: pointer; const Value: single);
    function GetBit(pval: pointer; BitIndex: integer): boolean;
    procedure SetBit(pval: pointer; BitIndex: integer; const Value: boolean);
  public
    procedure Reverse(pval : pointer; const S7Type : TS7Type);
    property ValBit[pval : pointer; BitIndex : integer] : boolean read GetBit write SetBit;
    property ValInt[pval : pointer] : smallint read GetInt write SetInt;
    property ValDInt[pval : pointer] : longint read GetDInt write SetDInt;
    property ValWord[pval : pointer] : word read GetWord write SetWord;
    property ValDWord[pval : pointer] : longword read GetDWord write SetDWord;
    property ValReal[pval : pointer] : single read GetReal write SetReal;
    property ValDateTime[pval : pointer] : TDateTime read GetDateTime write SetDateTime;
  end;

Var
  S7 : TS7Helper;

procedure TS7Helper.SetInt(pval: pointer; const Value: smallint);
Var
  BW : packed array[0..1] of byte absolute value;
begin
  pbyte(NativeInt(pval)+1)^:=BW[0];
  pbyte(pval)^:=BW[1];
end;
```

(I cut some code, so don't look for the implementation clause, etc... the helper class is compiling ok....)

Trivially, I want to invoke the SetInt property (as stated in the class documentation)... but the following code gives me an error "Cannot access private symbol TS7Helper.SetInt".

```
S7.SetInt(@MySnap7Array[i * 2], gaPlcDataScrittura[i]);
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Which Delphi version are you using?  There was a fairly "recent" (in version terms) in Class Helpers' ability to access private members of the helped class, which *may* be related to your problem.

Comment: @MartynA, note that this is not a [class helper](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers_(Delphi)) despite his name, but a real Delphi class.

Comment: I'm using Delphi Tokio 10.2 (quite the last version)

Comment: @JRL:  Well spotted, I didn't really look at the code.  Not such a great name to a class, istm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SetInt and GetInt is the getter and setter for ValInt property as stated in the definition of ValInt. So you shoud use S7.ValInt like

`S7.ValInt[@MySnap7Array[i * 2]] := gaPlcDataScrittura[i];`

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi,

> A [private member](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects_(Delphi)#Private.2C_Protected.2C_and_Public_Members) is invisible outside of the `unit` or `program` where its class is declared.

*Note: "program" refers to files starting with `program` keyword (usually the .dpr file), not to the project as a whole.*

So you can only call `TS7Helper.SetInt` from the same unit where `TS7Helper` class is declared.

Otherwise, @DmLam [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48839889/859646) is the correct way to solve it.